# ITopologicalOperator2 operation Simplify taking very long in ArcGIS 10.3.1

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, performance

I have a method that does a simplification of geometries. I have used this common code since ArGIS 9.2 without issues and it still works fine in ArGIS 10.2.2. Recently I upgraded a project to 10.3.1 and the simplify on the topology will every know and again freeze for anything between 30 seconds and 3 minutes. It doesn't happen every time and I have tested this on a simple polygon feature in a file geodatabase. Testing this on the same polygon feature in ArcGIS 10.2.2 does not give the performance issue. The code I use is:

```c#
    public IGeometry GetSimplifiedGeometry(IGeometry inGeometry)
    {
        var topo2 = inGeometry as ITopologicalOperator2;
        if (topo2 == null)
        {
            inGeometry.SnapToSpatialReference();
            return inGeometry;
        }
        topo2.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
        topo2.Simplify();
        inGeometry.SnapToSpatialReference();
        return topo2 as IGeometry;
    }
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Sounds odd, have you reported this to ESRI?

Comment: Yes we filled in a form to report the bug to Esri and also supplied a small test App to simulate the problem. It will probably take a few days for them to get back to us. But if someone has a work around to the issue it would be great.

Comment: @Samuel, did you get an answer from ESRI about this problem?